# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable エラーが出る

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、何故エラーが出てしまうのでしょうか。

▪️Test85.java

```
import java.util.function.*;

public class Test85 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      Hero85 h = new Hero85();
        (Cat85 c) -> {
            return c.getHp();
            }
    }
}
```

▪️Cat85.java

```
public interface Cat85 {
    public int hp;

    Cat85() {
        this.hp = 100;
    }

    public  abstract int getHp() {
        return this.hp;
    }

}
```

▪️Error Log

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to
     complete Expression
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

ご回答お願いします

Comment: 何がしたいんでしょうか？プログラムの目的というか期待する動作を説明頂けますか。 インターフェースにコンストラクタも書けないように思います。 エラーメッセージはラムダ式をアサインする変数が必須であると言ってるように思います。

Answer (score 2):

Cat85はインタフェースで宣言されています。そのため、以下のコンパイルエラーが出るかと思います。

- インタフェースがコンストラクタを持つことはできない

また、abstractメソッドで宣言されているgetHp()は、抽象メソッドですので、

- 抽象メソッドは本文を持つことはできない

とコンパイルエラーとなるでしょう。

Cat85を通常のJavaクラスにすればよいかと思いますので、例えば

```
public class Cat85 {
    public int hp;

    Cat85() {
        this.hp = 100;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return this.hp;
    }
}
```

として、Cat85インスタンスが実体化したときに変数hpに100が入ります。

おそらくTest85クラスで実装したいのは、抽象化されたCat85のインスタンスを取得して、そのhpの値などを取得しようとしたのではないかと思いますので、かんたんな例ですが、次のようにすると、java8から利用できるstreamAPIの機能を使って、Cat85のインスタンスを取得して、その中に入っているhpの値が返されます。

```
public class Test85 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Supplier<Cat85> supplier = () -> new Cat85();
        int hp = supplier.get().getHp();

        System.out.println(hp);
    }
}
```

おそらくSupprierで提供されるクラスが、インタフェースのCat85を実装した何かを返す、がしたかったのかと思います。